# Don't replace link if & exist after index.php?a=2

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace link `index.php?a=2` ,but if it's have `&` after `a=2` then don't replace it.

`index.php?a=2 <- replace
index.php?a=2&b=3 <- don't replace`

Using `PHP`, `preg_replace()`

I have tried using this:

```
preg_replace('^index\.php\?a=([0-9]+)(?!amp;)^', 'home', 'index.php?a=2');
preg_replace('^index\.php\?a=([0-9]+)(?!amp;)^', 'home', 'index.php?a=2&b=3');
preg_replace('^index\.php\?a=([0-9]+)(?!&)^', 'home', 'index.php?a=2');
preg_replace('^index\.php\?a=([0-9]+)(?!&)^', 'home', 'index.php?a=2&b=3');
```

That I'm using:

```
preg_replace('^(\/*)index\.php\?a=([0-9]+)(?!&)^e', "a($2)", 'index.php?a=2');

function a($id) {
  // Getting name from mysql...
  return '/a$id_$name';
}
```

It's working with this: `index.php?a=2&b0`, but with `index.php?a=10&b=0` not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***PHP Script:***

```
<?php
print preg_replace('/index\.php\?a=[0-9]+(?!&)/', 'home', 'index.php?a=2');
print "\n";
print preg_replace('/index\.php\?a=[0-9]+(?!&)/', 'home', 'index.php?a=2&b=3'); 
?>
```

***Output:***

```
home
index.php?a=2&b=3
```

Test the code [here](http://ideone.com/Y1Udp).

Comment: @nickb - Some competitors do that :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
'/index\.php\?a=[^&]+(?!&)/'
```

Comment: Imagine input like this: `<a href="index.php?a=1">You & Me</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
'/index\.php\?a=\d+(?!\s*&)/'
```

Comment: How can you have space character in valid url?